# How can I hide an element using jQuery based on the value of it's margin-left in the CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, margin

I'm developing a carousel style slider and want to hide one of the controls once the left margin of the `ul` equals -3480px. Here's my code:

```
$(function(){
    if($("ul#listName").css("margin-left") == "-3480px"){
      $(".nextButton").hide();
    }    
});
```

It's not doing anything though and I'm not sure what to do next. Has anyone got any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: use jquery UI, don't reinvent the wheel! ;)

Comment: also, get a JS fiddle set up, so we can see clearer what you are trying

Comment: The .css() method in jQuery returns the first element that matches your query. Are there multiple matches to "ul#listName"?

Comment: @MildFuzz i'd love to use jQuery UI but this is a really strange implementation of a carousel that's not for web.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works (adapted with different selectors, obviously). Have you checked that the list gets that margin? Maybe it's not getting that exact number, try inspecting with Firebug (or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what style property you are animating you should check that. Also make sure that convert the value into int before comparing because `css()` method will give the unit(px/em..) also along with its value.

```
    if(parseInt($("ul#listName").css("margin-left"), 10) == -3480){
        $(".nextButton").hide();
    }
```

If you are executing this code on any animation callback then I would suggest you to check for `<=` instead of `==` because the value may not be that perfect during animation. Try this.

```
    if(parseInt($("ul#listName").css("margin-left"), 10) <= -3480){
        $(".nextButton").hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mm = $("ul#listName").css("margin-left");
if(mm == -3480+"px"){
  $(".nextButton").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var leftMargin = parseInt($('ul#listName').css('margin-left'), 10);
if (leftMargin == -3480){
  $('.nextButton').hide();
}
```

I used `parseInt` to show an alternative and avoid any hangups you may have if/when `px` is suffixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var p = $(".your_class");
var position = p.position();
  if(p.position().left == '-3480px'){
$(".nextButton").hide();
}
```

Comment: `position` returns an object of numbers.

Comment: Yes and if you use position().left returns left position :) tested and use it in two sliders

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your full script to play with but I would recommend doing a `console.log()` on `$("ul#listName").css("margin-left")` to see if that actually outputs what you think it does. I would also use <= in case you're not hitting that exact value.

I'm just working off assumptions here but hopefully that will help.